# Only an expert can solve this

Tags: 18.04, updates, home-directory, symbolic-link, mountpoint

I tried to mount my `/dev/sdc` HDD to `/home`.

Then I tried to create a symlink to `/home` because my sdc HDD is 16tb.

Basically, I got what I wanted, but now everything is complicated:

- `wget` doesn't work.
- `apt-get` update doesn't work.
- Who knows what else is not working.

I need to find a solution so that I can apply future updates.

---

##### Here is fstab:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
# /dev/sdal
UUID=309fe0b5-68aa-4e85-92ed-45b616633e42 none swap sw 0 0
# /dev/ada2
UUID-359498b4-1260-4308-b4a8-db49d45a44d4 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
#/dev/sda3
UUID-dab2de9e-0047-44b9-873a-dd18791a7925 / ext4 defaults 0 0 
#/dev/ada4
UUID-croar554-93ea-437d-98ed-ed749cf94049 /home ext4 defaults 0 0
tmpts /home/xtreamcodes/iptv_xtream_codes/streams tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=90% 0 0
tmpfs /home/xtreamcodea/iptv_xtream_codes/tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=2G 0 0
# /dev/sdc   /home    ext4          nodev, nosuid       0       2
```

##### and here is my `lsblk` and `df -h`:

```
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /mnt/data2 # lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   32G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
├─sda3   8:3    0    2T  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0  1.7T  0 part /home
└─sda5   8:5    0    1M  0 part
sdb      8:16   0  3.7T  0 disk /mnt/data
sdc      8:32   0 14.6T  0 disk /mnt/data2

root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /mnt/data2 # df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  752K  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sdc        2.0T  740G  1.2T  40% /
tmpfs            32G   16K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc         15T  2.7T   12T  20% /home
/dev/sda2       975M  149M  775M  17% /boot
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   1% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb        3.6T  3.1T  394G  89% /mnt/data

root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /mnt/data2 # 


                                                         Activate Windows
                                                         Go to Settings to activate Windows.
```

##### Error for `# apt-get update`:

```
zoot@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal ~ # apt-get update
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic
  Could not resolve " pps.launchpad.net "
Err:2 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages bionic InRelease 
  Could not resolve " mirror.hetzner.de "
Err:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve "de.archive, ubuntu.com "
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com
Err:5 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'mirror.hetzner.de'
Err:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages bionic-mecurity InRelease
  Could not resolve 'mirror.hetrner.de'
Err:9 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'mirror.hetzner.de'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packagea/dists/bionic/InRelease Could not resolve 'mirror.hetzner.de'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packagea/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease Could not resolve 'mirror.hetzner.de'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packagea/dists/bionic-security/InRelease Could not resolve 'mirror.hetzner.de'
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packagea/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease Could not resolve 'mirror.hetzner.de'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'

zoot@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal ~ # 

                                                         Activate Windows
                                                         Go to Settings to activate Windows.
```

##### Error for `wget`:

```
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal ~ # wget
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try 'wget --help" for more options.

zoot@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal ~ # wget https://od.lk/d/MIFfMzY4N134HDRf/Darlin%20%20%282019%29%20%5BDarlin%20%20%282019%29%5D.mp4
--2023-08-31 22:43:22-- https://od.1k/a/h1fcнаt4иjmWnDRE/Darlin%20%20%282019%29%20%5BDarlin%20%20%282019%29%5D.mp4
Resolving od.lk (od.lk)… failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `od.lk’

zoot@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal ~ #


                                                         Activate Windows
                                                         Go to Settings to activate Windows.
```

Comment: There is a function to share pictures into your question instead of referencing remote urls which will vanish. Despite that, you could simply copy the contents of your terminal and paste it (formatted) into your question -would make things much easier.

Comment: You are using 18.04 Bionic which is End of life and not supported anymore. I recommend to install a recent version of Ubuntu instead of trying to fix issues in an outdated system.

Comment: I agree with @mook765.  Your errors you are seeing when you do the `apt-get update` are errors that it cannot reach those repositories.  Those repositories all got moved when Ubuntu 18.04 went EOL so what you are seeing is normal.  The names of those sites cannot resolve because they no longer exist.  Your `/home` mount shouldn't be causing network issues.  Upgrade the system to a supported release.

Comment: If you don't mind losing your data, you could simply reinstall a newer, supported version of Ubuntu (like Ubuntu 20.04 "Focal" or 22.04 Ubuntu "Jammy", for example). **Alternatively**, you can follow [these instructions to upgrade your EOL version of Ubuntu to a newer, supported version](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/167115) while keeping your current data and current setup. I've never performed an upgrade on a WSL version of Ubuntu like this if that's what you're using but I assume it should work just the same. In any case, go ahead and back up all your data and other stuff before you begin.

Comment: Are you not creating partitions on sdb & sdc? You need to have gpt partitions and format the partition(s), not a drive. Just about all tools expect to see partitions.

Comment: I'll add that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is **not** end-of-life or EOL, it's only EOSS or *end of standard support*, meaning mirrors & unofficial (inc. 3rd party) repositories are free to drop support if they wish, and PRO or ESM is required to download/install upgraded packages from the main archive (or mirrors that still provide support).  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/   (The main archive will still provide packages if you don't have ESM/Pro, but you won't get updated packages but those frozen at EOSS)

Answer (score 2):

Don't symlink home - that's your user, whereas your "external home" will probably have another user.

Create some folder in your "original" home directory and mount your "external home" into that directory.

Then you'll have all of your 16 TB in a folder, which you can reach from "home